# Extend typescript definitelyTyped definition file

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, definitelytyped

I'm getting the following error:

> src/models/priceAdjustment.ts(55,2): error TS2345: Argument of type '{ as: string; foreignKey: string; gql: any; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AssociationOptionsHasMany'.
>     Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'gql' does not exist in type 'AssociationOptionsHasMany'.

The error is obvious, I'm trying to assign a "gql" key which doesn't exist (I'm attaching it on so I can access it later on in my code somewhere else).

What I'd like to do, is extend the [`model.hasMany` interface here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/sequelize/index.d.ts#L1326), and add my own key. Is this possible? If so, how do I?

My current workaround is to cast the object to `<any>` before passing it in, which feels like a dirty workaround.

I have attempted the following:

```
import Sequelize from 'sequelize';

export declare module Sequelize {
    export interface MyAssociationOptionsHasMany extends Sequelize.AssociationOptionsHasMany {
        gql?: any
    }
    export interface MyAssociations extends Sequelize.Associations {
        hasMany(target: Sequelize.Model<any, any>, options?: MyAssociationOptionsHasMany): void;
    }
}
```

And now I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '239' of undefined
    at getDeclarationSpaces (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsc.js:33121:54)
    at checkExportsOnMergedDeclarations (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsc.js:33067:41)
    at checkModuleDeclaration (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsc.js:35036:17)
    at checkSourceElement (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsc.js:35505:28)
    at Object.forEach (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsc.js:275:30)
    at checkSourceFileWorker (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsc.js:35566:20)
    at checkSourceFile (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsc.js:35551:13)
    at getDiagnosticsWorker (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsc.js:35604:17)
    at Object.getDiagnostics (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsc.js:35593:24)
    at C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsc.js:56188:85
```

Comment: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped#how-can-i-contribute

Comment: @Mörre Since this is a property that I created specifically for my application, and has no relation to sequelize (Other than in my app), it's wrong to commit that change to the repository.

Comment: Typescript does [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html), so you should be able to create your own definition file with your addition to the interface.

Comment: try looking for _merging declarations_ in the documentation

Answer (score 4):

You can do this via [Declaration Merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html).  The best way I have found this to work is by importing the library into an "extension" file and extending the library from there.  For instance,

`extensions/library-name.extension.ts`:

```
import AssociationOptionsHasMany from '/path/to/definition';
import 'library-name';

declare module 'library-name' {
  interface InterfaceToExtend {
    hasMany(options: AssociationOptionsHasMany): ReturnType;
  }
}
```

In the above example, we want to extend an Interface created in the `library-name` module.  Since we are using imports, TypeScript automatically creates a module for the file, so we have to tell TypeScript that we want to extend the interface in the `library-name` module, not the module created for this file.  To do that, we simply `declare` the module using the same name as the library we imported.

After telling TypeScript in which module the interface should be extended, we just use Declaration Merging by defining an interface with the same name as the interface that should be extended and adding whatever we need to it.  In this case, that would be a new method that takes as an argument the specific type we want to pass it.

I have also had to update the `tsconfig.json` file so the extensions would be loaded first.  You can do that by including the `extensions` directory before the rest of the app:

```
{
  /* Blah, settings, blah */
  includes: ['./app/extensions/*.ts', './app/**/*.ts'],
  /* Blah, settings, blah */
}
```

If you're using Sublime, it might complain still, but actually compiling the code or exiting out of Sublime and reopening it seems to work just fine.

**A word of warning.**  Declaration Merging is powerful, but can result in unexpected behavior.  In general, try to avoid extending components you (or someone else) have defined elsewhere.  If may be a sign that you are using these components incorrectly or the need for refactoring.  Remember, the benefit of TypeScript is strict(er) typing.

Comment: I've updated my question with another issue I'm encountering.

Comment: @FrankerZ Try `export interface MyAssociationOptionsHasMany { /*...*/` instead of `export interface MyAssociationOptionsHasMany extends Sequelize.MyAssociationOptionsHasMany { /* ... */ }` and something similar for `MyAssociations`.  I'm not too familiar with Sequelize, so I can't give too many specifics for Sequelize.

Comment: @FrankerZ please consider accepting this answer. It answers your question :)