# How do I extend a class definition that's missing types from DefinitelyTyped?

Tags: typescript, selenium-webdriver

I want to use the `Driver` instance method `setNetworkConditions` from `selenium-webdriver`, which is [available in the source](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/66b14c5578a915ae5b931ad857d0cd341c361377/javascript/node/selenium-webdriver/chromium.js#L709-L737).

DefinitelyTyped is currently missing the types for this function. In fact, all it has is this:

```js
export class Driver extends webdriver.WebDriver {
  /**
   * Creates a new session with the ChromeDriver.
   *
   * @param {(Capabilities|Options)=} opt_config The configuration options.
   * @param {(remote.DriverService|http.Executor)=} opt_serviceExecutor Either
   *     a  DriverService to use for the remote end, or a preconfigured executor
   *     for an externally managed endpoint. If neither is provided, the
   *     {@linkplain ##getDefaultService default service} will be used by
   *     default.
   * @return {!Driver} A new driver instance.
   */
  static createSession(
      opt_config?: Options|webdriver.CreateSessionCapabilities,
      opt_service?: remote.DriverService|http.Executor): Driver;
}
```

I want to extend this definition within my `ambient.d.ts` file, which I have successfully used for projects that do not have any TS definitions at all.

Now, how go about doing this? I have tried adding this:

```js
declare module 'selenium-webdriver/chrome' {
  class Driver {
    setNetworkConditions(spec: {});
  }
}
```

But as soon as I add this, all other function type definitions from the `Driver` class that it inherits from `webdriver.WebDriver` appear as missing.

I have [seen this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47422588/extend-typescript-definitelytyped-definition-file) but it does not seem to match the use case of extending existing definitions.

How could I *merge* the definitions, or extend them, without having to copy-paste the DefinitelyTyped definitions for `webdriver.WebDriver`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a rather dirty workaround. I have to create a completely new interface:

```
export interface ChromeDriverNetworkConditionsSpec {
  offline?: boolean;
  latency: number;
  download_throughput: number; // in Bit/s
  upload_throughput: number; // in Bit/s
}

export interface DriverWithNetworkOptions {
  getNetworkConditions(): Promise<ChromeDriverNetworkConditionsSpec>;
  setNetworkConditions(spec: ChromeDriverNetworkConditionsSpec): Promise<void>;
}
```

Then, use it like so:

```
const driver = // create webdriver as usual
await (driver as unknown as DriverWithNetworkOptions).setNetworkConditions({
  // ...
});
```

This will mask all other properties, but if you only use it in one place, that can be managed, e.g. by abstracting it away in another function.